# Is it possible to virtualise any CPU on any other CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu, virtualization

I recently got a Raspberry Pi and read a lot of blog post about projects on it, and wanted to try a few of them. But I also read that SD cards don't have a high life duration if we (re)write many times to it. So I wanted to try the images for the Pi project on a virtual OS (with Virtualbox preferably).

So I wanted to know if it is possible for me to virtualize the ARM CPU on my own laptop CPU. For the record, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and `uname -a` responds with:

```
Linux Laptop 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
```

But as I'm curious, I'd like to know if it is possible to virtualize any CPU on any other CPU. Is it something hardware related, or software related?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My best guess regarding what your actual question is would be that you're asking whether or not _any general purpose CPU on the market today can emulate any other CPU_, In theory, that's obviously the case. In practice, the worst case is that one may end up having to emulate the whole hardware platform (or at least a significant amount of it), which will be horribly slow most of the time, up to the point where the emulation concept becomes unsuitable because many applications are based on implicit assumptions about the platform performance.

Comment: This is a very broad question that will invite all kinds of impractical answers with deep theory about, for example, whether hardware can or cannot mine true randomness.

Comment: Virtualization is quite different from emulation, which is more in line with what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the RPi question, have a look at [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/how-to-run-raspbian-on-virtualbox)
(essentially you can use something like [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to run the images).

To answer the main question:

> Is it possible to virtualize any CPU on any other CPU?

Yes (to an extent), however, it might not be as efficient as you might think. And it should be noted that VirtualBox/VMWare type of virtualization is different than what you are asking, which is actually `Is it possible to EMULATE any CPU on any other CPU?`.

CPU's are hardware components that have a specific set of instructions (also known as op-codes) hard-wired into them; these op-codes are specific numeric values that can be translated at an electrical level such that the CPU will actually 'do something'.

When software is written to tell the CPU to 'do something' (like a calculator), the software must be built (targeted) for a specific CPU. That is to say, that my software must be compiled (translated) and assembled such that the machine instructions can be understood by the machine I am running my software on, otherwise, IF it runs at all, I might not get the EXACT results that I'm expecting. The assembly instructions (op-codes) for something like 2+2 on an ARM might not exactly match the assembly instructions on a PIC or FPGA, and what I would get back would be garbage (again, IF it ran).

Each CPU 'does something' a little differently, much how I can write in the English language to convey my thoughts to you, I could also convey the same thoughts in Spanish or Japanese, though I'd have to convey them quite differently due not only to the syntactical differences in English/Spanish/Japanese but the differences in how those languages are contextually parsed as well. If you and I were talking (vs. written communication), and you only spoke Japanese and I Spanish, then we would need a translator who was fluent in both languages in order to properly communicate, though it would be slower than direct communication because we need our languages to be properly parsed so nothing is "lost in translation".

This is the same concept with CPU 'virtualization/emulation'. If you want to run applications that were not built for the CPU you are running on (i.e. I want to run ARM software on my x86 PC), then a program needs to take the ARM assembly and translate to the x86 assembly, so that a call to `draw word on screen` isn't instead a call for `erase RAM location X`.

This is why it's not necessarily feasible to properly emulate any CPU on any other CPU (if at all since one can't really emulate x86 on a PIC per se). CPU's do a LOT more than just 'crunch numbers', and they do all of this 'more-ness' VERY fast, and a lot require the timing of it all to be exact. When you emulate a CPU, you are essentially adding a translation layer between the software and the hardware. Adding this layer could add a significant amount of time to the execution of the instructions due to how many extra instructions might need be executed. This added time *might* be so much time that the software becomes unresponsive or just generally unusable (like playing a video game at 1 frame per second, sure you can do it, but it'll take 2 minutes just to write the 'press start' text on screen).

It should be noted that if the hardware (the CPU), has the same instruction set built in, it must 'do the same thing' as the other instruction set is intend; i.e. (patent/license issues aside) Intel could decide to add the instruction sets for the ARM processor into a line of it's x86_64 CPU's so that you could potentially run the ARM binaries direct on that CPU, but they would still have to have the architecture 'do' as the ARM architecture 'does' or the output might not be exact.

So, it might be possible to emulate one type of CPU on another type of CPU, but depending on how/what is emulated, it might be so slow as to be deemed unrunnable, or might be indistinguishable from a human perspective (i.e. subjectively it's "as fast" as running on the native hardware, but technically speaking it's not).

I hope that can help add some clarity.

Comment: " I hope that can help add some clarity." You definitly did. Sharp, simple ans clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) to emulate *any* CPU as a virtual machine on an Ubuntu box.

from their main page -

> QEMU is a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer.
>
> When used as a machine emulator, QEMU can run OSes and programs made for one machine (e.g. an ARM board) on a different machine (e.g. your own PC). By using dynamic translation, it achieves very good performance.

There is a specific article on setting it up [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment) but if you search "ubuntu qemu raspberry" it will yield a huge number of responses to get you on the right path.

The last part of your question, is a wholly different beast! and something that Alan Turing put a great deal of thought into. Its not an answer - because I'm no where near smart enough to sum it all up - but you should start at the [Universal Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) which was his approach to that exact question.